# Quicksort-algorithm in java not sorting correctly (first element as pivot)

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am working on an assignment where we are supposed to implement quicksort, with the first element as pivot. There is a small error in my code that causes the elements of the list (used for testing) to sort incorrectly. The output should be **1 3 7 8 9 10** but ends up being **1 7 3 8 9 10** (7 and 3 should switch place). I suspect that the error may be somewhere between row 15-26 but I can´t seem to find it, despite many tries to fix it.

Anyone who can see anything wrong?

(In the first while-loop, I´ve tried having i <= j instead of i < j but that seems to result in an endless loop. Have seen that work in other examples but don´t know why that dos not work in my case)

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (!(hi > lo)) {
        return;
    }
    int pivot = a[lo];
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi + 1;
    int temp;
    i++;
    j--;
    while (i < j) {
        while (a[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            switchPlace(a, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    switchPlace(a, lo, j);
    quickSort(a, lo, j - 1);
    quickSort(a, j + 1, hi);
}

public static void switchPlace(int[] a, int x, int y) {
    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}

public static void printList(int[] a) {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        res += a[i] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 9, 3, 10, 1, 8, 7 };
    quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    printList(a);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Yeah sorry, realized that just after I posted it. Changed that.

Comment: http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/quick-sort/

This might be useful

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that @Lakindu

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe here a simple approach to debugging such algorithms, which consists of:

1. making some expectations about what smaller portions of the code should produce;
2. verifying that those expectations are satisfied.

The first point involves understanding in some detail what the code attempts to do, while the second point implies using some tool to make the checks. The "tool" exemplified in this particular answer consists of using `print` messages, but in general it can be something else (*e.g.* a step debugger).

---

The main operation of the qsort algorithm is swapping of elements around the pivot, so that the smaller values are before, and larger values are after it.
This process occurs for various subsequences between the `lo` and `hi` indices.

Now let's check whether this operation is done correctly for each subsequence.
To this end, we can display the initial subsequence, as well as the subsequence after the swaps occurred, so that we can afterwards manually check if this operation is performed correctly.

We can use something like this code before the swapping part:

```
    System.out.print("before: ");
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        System.out.print(a[k] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

And something like this after the swapping part:

```
    System.out.print("after: ");
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        System.out.print(a[k]);
        if (k == j) {
            System.out.print(" (pivot)");
        }
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
```

The output for the sequence in the example looks like this:

> before: 9, 3, 10, 1, 8, 7,
>   after: 8, 3, 7, 1, 9 (pivot), 10,
>
> before: 8, 3, 7, 1,
>   after: 1, 3, 7, 8 (pivot),
>
> before: 1, 3, 7,
>   after: 1 (pivot), 3, 7,
>
> before: 3, 7,
>   after: 7, 3 (pivot),

We can see that a problem occurs for the last sub-sequence, of length 2.
The advantage is that we can now only focus on this situation and understand exactly what happens.

For example we can even pass to the algorithm directly `int[] a = {3, 7};`.

After carefully considering what happens in that case, we can see that the problem consist of the `j` index not jumping over the elements larger than the pivot, because the `while (i < j)` exits immediately in such a situation (we have i == j from the start). There are multiple solutions, one that seems to work is to use `while (i <= j)` in the respective condition -- despite you explicitly mentioned that it might lead to an infinite loop, it does not seem to be the case actually.

Below is the code containing this fix (along with the additional `print`s described above):

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (!(hi > lo)) {
        return;
    }
    int pivot = a[lo];
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi + 1;
    int temp;
    i++;
    j--;

    System.out.print("before: ");
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        System.out.print(a[k] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    while (i <= j) {
        while (a[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (a[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            switchPlace(a, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    switchPlace(a, lo, j);

    System.out.print("after: ");
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        System.out.print(a[k]);
        if (k == j) {
            System.out.print(" (pivot)");
        }
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    quickSort(a, lo, j - 1);
    quickSort(a, j + 1, hi);
}

public static void switchPlace(int[] a, int x, int y) {
    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}

public static void printList(int[] a) {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        res += a[i] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //int[] a = {3, 7};
    //int[] a = { 9, 3, 10, 1, 8, 7 };
    int[] a = {24, 2 , 45 ,20 ,56 ,75 ,2 ,56 ,99 ,53 ,12};
    quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    printList(a);
}
```

Comment: Adding that little = in the first while-loop seemes to do the trick! Even though that's odd since it did not work before, I won't complain since it works now. Many thanks for your detailed and educational reply, it helps alot! @qwertyman

Comment: @Isus no problem, glad it helped. Maybe there were some other modifications made after the last try of using "=" in the while-loop.

Comment: @Isus Also, I'm happy that you see this answer as being educational. When it got down-voted i was afraid that it might have sounded arrogant :-) which was by no means my intention. Making expectations and checking them is essential (regardless the technique being based on using prints, a debugger, or anything else), and often not explained during programming courses.

Comment: I most likely did some other modifications. Though I can´t remember which, I did so many in order to find the error. I thought your answer was very extensive and well explained. I was suprised myself when it got downvoted, I don´t think it sounded arrogant at all :) @qwertyman

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] a, int lo, int hi) {
        if (!(hi > lo)) {
            return;
        }
        int pivot = a[lo];
        int i = lo - 1;
        int j = hi + 1;
        int temp;
        while (i < j) {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (a[i] < pivot);
            do {
                j--;
            } while (a[j] > pivot);
            if (i < j) {
                switchPlace(a, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        switchPlace(a, lo, j);
        quickSort(a, lo, j - 1);
        quickSort(a, j + 1, hi);
    }
```

Comment: At first it seemed your solution worked, since it gave the correct output for `int[] a = { 9, 3, 10, 1, 8, 7 };` . Tried another input, which unfortunately failed. Tried `int[] a = {24, 2 , 45 ,20 ,56 ,75 ,2 ,56 ,99 ,53 ,12};` which gave the output `2 2 20 12 75 45 56 24 53 56 99 `. @Robert D. Mogos

Comment: Don't just say "This fixes it". Please indicate the changes you've made and exlpain them.